# I am adding an ImageView in android app in android studio. The image size is 1.93MB. When I am running the AVD, app is getting closed due to an error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development

This is the error I am getting :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(115781908bytes) bitmap.

Is there any way by which I can fix this without reducing the image quality?

Comment: try using the `largeHeap = true` manifest flag. Do note that, this will not solve nor fix your issue, it will only postpone/delay it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a 1.93 MB image.  That's a 110MB image.  The compressed size of the file isn't what matters, its the uncompressed size-  which is `4*width*height`.

Why is your image so large, in terms of width and height?  That's over 5300x5300.  You need a smaller image.  Reducing the quality wouldn't help, as the uncompressed size would be the same.

Edit:  Fixed initial math where I was off by a suffix. However the math on the pixel size was correct.

Comment: It's 110MB. 115781908bytes = 113068.x kilobytes = 110.4 megabytes. 

but it's still huge, and will likely end up with OutOfMemory exceptions regardless of what he does with it's compression.

Comment: @Shark you're right, something fried in my brain on that math.  I've fixed it.  Luckily my pixel math was correct.

Comment: @GabeSechan its ok, i already understood that, 
thanks for your explanation, it really helped me understand the concept of uncompressed size

Comment: we all have brainfarts gabe, and it's pretty hot outside. :)

Answer (score 0):

115,781,908 Bytes is nearly equal to 115 MB.

If you could export it with SVG that would be better of course.